# ls implementation in C

Tags: c, unix

I wrote a program in C which has the same functionality as `ls, ls-l, ls-a` in UNIX. Now what I want to do is to print the data in the same way as the orginal ls(in columns with 1 space distance). I know that i need to use a `printf("%*s",size,string)` when making columns, but the column size depends on the longest word in the column. How could I do it simple?. My only idea is first, to collect all data in some structure, then check the longest element and save the length to a variable, which will be the size of the column.

Comment: That seems a valid algorithm. Any problem with it?

Comment: What do you want to do else? The longest name you cannot guess, so you have to calculate it by checking all names.

Comment: Regarding to the structure, I was programming some time in C++ where I would use something from sdl, like vector, how about C?

Comment: Try to use tabulators (`\t`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just looked it up in GNU coreutils how it does it and that's basically the way to do it.

There is one corner cases when the algorithm will print only one line at a time: you asked for one entry per line, did a non-recursive search, demanded not to sort the entries and you didn't explicitely tell ls to use a certain block size.

In every other case it does basically what you specified. 
For the structure i'd recommend an array of structs that you allocate somewhat generously and reallocate exponentially if you run out. In case you encounter a memory shortage or if you decide from the start you want to conserve memory you could still dump onto the screen what you already have up to that point.

Little addendum the coreutils ls doesn't even use %*s, instead it putchars spaces (i guess for portability with ancient/broken libcs), but both should work.

As for the question, if you interested, have a look around http://www.artfiles.org/gnu.org/coreutils/coreutils-8.20.tar.xz